# how to delete src folder after test cases compiled?

Tags: jenkins

I am running the selenium test cases through jenkins. once the workspace is created and src folder is also there. I do not want the src folder to be exposed to all the users. how should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

To restrict from other users,revoke the RWX permission  for others(groups as well) to that directory and subdirectory using execute shell.

```
chmod -R o-rwx src
```

Here no role to play for jenkins

Comment: Go to job -> configuration> build step> add build step execute shell.... for more you search stack.. there are many answers available for exeute shell

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.

I used WS clean up plugin and it is able to delete the workspace or specified files and folders.